# Will writeToFile:atomically: overwrite data?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Really simple question but it doesn't seem to be clear in Apple's docs.

Will `writeToFile:atomically:` for `NSData`, `NSArray` etc. overwrite existing data on a file?

Answer (score 222, accepted):

Yes. `writeToFile:atomically:` will.

Comment: Whether you do it atomically or not doesn't matter; in either case, the file will be completely overwritten with the new data.

Comment: Ah, but for me it fails, and the original file is intact. As writeToFile does not return an NSError, how can I investigate the failure? it may be a permissions issue, but I can't be sure. My code runs as an Installer Plugin Bundle, for an installation package that demands root privileges -- I don't know how to verify/printout the privileges with which my code is run.

Comment: @MottiShneor You could use -writeToURL:options:error: instead, which does have an error parameter.

Answer (score 7):

Method `writeToFile:atomically:` **ALWAYS OVERWRITE FILE**, regardless of the `atomically:` YES or NO.

Information from [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata) (NSData, section "Saving Data"):

> The NSData class and its subclasses provide methods to quickly and
>   easily save their contents to disk. To minimize the risk of data loss,
>   these methods provide the option of saving the data atomically. Atomic
>   writes guarantee that the data is either saved in its entirety, or it
>   fails completely. The atomic write begins by writing the data to a
>   temporary file. If this write succeeds, then the method moves the
>   temporary file to its final location.

No one word about checking if file exist.

For example, for method `copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:` in [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsfilemanager/1407903-copyitematpath) (NSFileManager, section Discussion) specifically written about such checking:

> If a file with the same name already exists at dstPath, this method
>   stops the copy attempt and returns an appropriate error.